# How do I add inline styling in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble re positioning this button without moving all the buttons on the entire site. Here is the code I want to add inline styling. For example i want to add the button positioning as "absolute".

```
 <Button href={LINKS.application} external>
      Join today!
    </Button>
```

Here is the button component code:

```
const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ children, external, iconName, disabled, href, target, ...props }) => {
  if (href)
    return (
      <Link href={href}>
        <a
          href={href}
          target={target ?? (external ? '_blank' : '_self')}
          className={`font-secondary text-xs md:text-base flex flex-row items-center gap-2 bg-white rounded-xl px-5 py-4 text-content-button font-bold hover:opacity-70 duration-300 ${
            disabled ? 'cursor-not-allowed opacity-70' : 'cursor-pointer'
          }`}
        >
          {!!iconName && <Icon iconName={iconName} />}
          <span>{children}</span>
          {external && <Icon iconName="arrow" />}
        </a>
      </Link>
    )
```

[image: This is how it looks right now, Too LONG.]

[image: This is how I want it to look.]

Please let me know if you have a solution

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<div style={{color:"red"}}>foobar</div>
```

And for the next time:
If you google "react inline style" and click on the first link you will probably find your answer.

Comment: Thanks. The inline didnt work. I edited my question to add pictures of what I want it to look like. The first picture is how it looks now and the second picture is what I want it to be. When I switched it to absolute position on the component it worked but it messed with all the other buttons on the page. What should i try next?

Comment: it seems like you have a problem with all your classes. i would suggest to write your own css style. Its not that complicated. If you dont want to write your own css try to add `style={{width: "100px"}}` to your a tag and look if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

A better method would be to use a classname that references a CSS file or module.

However it can be accomplished with `<button style={{position:"absolute"}}>Hey I'm a  button</button>`

Generally using position absolute in this context is likely not best practice as well.

Comment: Thanks. The inline didnt work. I edited my question to add pictures of what I want it to look like. The first picture is how it looks now and the second picture is what I want it to be. When I switched it to absolute position on the component it worked but it messed with all the other buttons on the page. What should i try next? @Ben

Comment: My understanding is you're using all this button component all over the site, so you need to add a styles prop to the component, then pass that styles prop down into the actual html element itself.